# What is the best way to do a drive subst with Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a tool to allow the ability to create a substitute drive from one drive to another, not a network location.  I have a python file setup and tried a number of different ways to do this but am having trouble.

If I use "subst O: D:\", in a cmd prompt, it works great.  However, I need to do this action within a python call like os.system() or subproces.run() but these either doesn't do anything or produces an error that is not useful.
I have tried to run the direct command as well as write out a .bat file with the cmd in it and it also does not seem to work, even though, I can manually run the .bat file and that works.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you be more specific than "error that is not useful" and "does not seem to work"?

Comment: If I surround the calls with a try: it often fails with an ambiguous failed call.  if I don't surround the call, I get nothing, and no errors are reported.

        subst_cmd = 'subst O: ' + self.target_drive + ':\\\\'
        try:
            p = subprocess.run(subst_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

the above example reports nothing, that I can see, and does not perform the task.

Comment: What is "an ambiguous failed call"?

Comment: "Could not find the specified drive" was one, I am sorry I didn't capture the others and I have tried so many different ways.